# Get fully-qualified path of Protobuf message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I am trying to get the fully-qualified path of my Protobuf message type in JavaScript.  For example, given the following file: `status.proto`

```
package my.messages.proto; 

message Status {
   string code = 1;
}
```

Once compiled with protoc, I can then do something like:

```
import { Status } from 'gen/my/messages/proto/status_pb.js';

const status = new Status();
```

But then how can I get the fully-qualified path of this message?  I want a string of `my.messages.proto.Status`, but I can't seem to find any API where this is possible.  I basically want the equivalent of the C++ function `message.GetDescriptor()->full_name()`.

If I do `console.log(status);`, I see something printed out like:

```
my.messages.proto.Status {wrappers_: null, messageId_: undefined, arrayIndexOffset_: -1, array: Array(1), pivot_: 1.7976931348623157e+308, …}
```

So, the information is there, but just not sure how I can access it.  Is this possible in JavaScript with Protobuf?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Stuck on it as well! If not, what was your solution?

Comment: I actually never really did.  However, if I could offer a shameless plug for a library my new company has created:  https://github.com/bufbuild/protobuf-es.  Much easier to do many things, including getting the FQname (`typeName` property on the message).

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing. I dod come across that while I was researching. We managed to get by with the solution below. If we run into more troubles I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

All the proto message types generated using `protoc_node` are available on the global `proto` namespace in node as a `key:class` object. So you can check whether your message is an instance of one of the key's values and return the key:

```
import { MessageType } from './MessageType_pb'

const message = new MessageType()

export function getSubjectFromMessage(message: Message){
  for (const key in proto){
    if(message instanceof proto[key]){
      return key
    }
  }
}

getSubjectFromMessage(message) === "MessageType" // true
```

Nasty that they don't provide a `class.name` or something.